# Android Media Player plays sound only once

Tags: android, media-player

```
public void playClickSound() {
AssetFileDescriptor afd;
MediaPlayer sound = new MediaPlayer();  
    try {

        sound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        afd = getAssets().openFd("click.mp3");

sound.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        sound.prepare();
        sound.start();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is my code for playing sound. I call this method on a few buttons in mu GUI.
It works fine the first time i press the button, but second time i get IllegalStateException.
What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Can you show the logcat record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manage the life-cycle of the Media Player. Following the below flow, should work out:

```
RefreshPlayer()
{
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
             {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();    
            }
        }
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getSherlockActivity(),
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(VidPath)));
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```